# How to loop though columns and subset the dataset according to the same value

Tags: r, loops, subset, data-management

I am attempting to loop through columns and subset data with the same value.

See Below.

```
White <- rep(0:1, 50)
Latino <- rep(0:1, 50)
Black <- rep(0:1, 50)
Asian <- rep(0:1, 50)
DV <- seq(1: length(rep(0:1, 50)))
x <- data.frame(cbind(White, Latino, Black, Asian, DV))


race <- c("White", "Latino", "Black", "Asian")

for(j in race){
  for (i in race){

    df_1 <- subset(x, i == 1)
    df_2 <- subset(x, j == 1)
    print(paste(i, j, sep = " "))
    print(t.test(df_1$DV, df_2$DV) )


  }
}
```

Unfortunately, r does not like the i or j to stand alone. If anyone knows a better way of looping through columns to subset the same value, It would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `i` and `j` in your code is a string, but actually you wanted to extract that column, like

```r
for(j in race){
  for (i in race){

    df_1 <- subset(x, x[,i] == 1)
    df_2 <- subset(x, x[,j] == 1)
    print(paste(i, j, sep = " "))
    print(t.test(df_1$DV, df_2$DV) )


  }
}
```

---

With regarding to a better way of looping, it seems the dummy variable `White`, `Latino`, `Black` and `Asian` is mutually exclusive, therefore, perhaps we could rearrange data into

```
      race  DV
   ------------
1    Black   1
2    White   2
3   Latino   3
4    Black   4
5    Asian   5
```

and invoke `t.test` with formula, like

```r
# generate synthetic data
rnd.race <- sample(1:4, 50, replace=T)
x <- data.frame(
  White = as.integer(rnd.race == 1),
  Latino = as.integer(rnd.race == 2),
  Black = as.integer(rnd.race == 3),
  Asian = as.integer(rnd.race == 4),
  DV = seq(1: length(rep(0:1, 50)))
)

race <- c("White", "Latino", "Black", "Asian")

# rearrange data, gather columns of dummy variables
x.cleaned = data.frame(
  race = race[apply(x[,1:4], 1, which.max)],
  DV = x$DV
)

t.test( DV ~ race, data=x.cleaned, race %in% c("White", "Black"))

# 
#     Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  DV by race
# t = -0.91517, df = 42.923, p-value = 0.3652
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -25.241536   9.483961
# sample estimates:
# mean in group Black mean in group White 
#            47.66667            55.54545 
#
```

The eensy benefit of using `t.test` with formula is its readability. For example, in the report of `t.test`, instead of `mean in group x` and `mean in group y`, it will say `mean in group Black`, `mean in group White`, and the formula itself states the variable at which we are testing covariant against.

To run t-test iteratively across all pairs, we could

```r
run.test = function(race.pair) {
    list(t.test(DV ~ race, data=x.cleaned, race %in% race.pair) )
}

combn(race, 2, FUN = run.test)

# [[1]]
# 
#     Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  DV by race
# t = -0.30892, df = 41.997, p-value = 0.7589
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -21.22870  15.59233
# sample estimates:
# mean in group Latino  mean in group White 
#             52.72727             55.54545 
# 
# 
# [[2]]
# 
#     Welch Two Sample t-test
# 
# data:  DV by race
# t = -0.91517, df = 42.923, p-value = 0.3652
# alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
# 95 percent confidence interval:
#  -25.241536   9.483961
# sample estimates:
# mean in group Black mean in group White 
#            47.66667            55.54545 
# 
# ...
```

where `combn(x, m, FUN = NULL, simplify = TRUE, ...)` is a builtin to generate all combinations of the elements of `x` taken `m` at a time. For a more generate case using `outer`, see [@askrun's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56944572/759732).

---

Finally, IMHO, perhaps ANOVA is more widely recognized than t-test when comparing means between three or more groups (may also suggest why it is "inconvenient" to use t-test iteratively over pairs of groups).

With `x.cleaned`, we can easily use ANOVA in R, like:

```r
aov.out = aov(DV ~ race, data=x.cleaned)
summary(aov.out)
```

Note that after one-way ANOVA (test if some of the group means are different), we may also run Post Hoc tests (like `TukeyHSD(aov.out)`) to find out specific pairs of group has different means. A few tests of assumptions are also *de rigueur* in a formal report. [Here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/bwebb/statistics/ANOVA_in_R.pdf) is a lecture notes related to this. And [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/403517/t-test-anova-or-regression-whats-the-difference) is a related question on Cross-Validated (where further questions on which test to choose could be answered).

Comment: Awesome! Thank so you much for the help. That worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to assist, enjoy coding!

Answer (score 2):

In `R`, we can also do this with `outer`

```
f1 <- function(u, v) list(t.test(x$DV[x[[u]] ==1], x$DV[x[[v]] == 1]))
out <- outer(race, race, FUN = Vectorize(f1))
out[1,1]
#[[1]]

#   Welch Two Sample t-test

#data:  x$DV[x[[u]] == 1] and x$DV[x[[v]] == 1]
#t = 0, df = 98, p-value = 1
#alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#95 percent confidence interval:
# -11.57133  11.57133
#sample estimates:
#mean of x mean of y 
#       51        51
```

It can be made into a `list` output

```
lst1 <-  setNames(lapply(out, I), outer(race, race, FUN = paste)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `get`

```
for(j in race){
     for (i in race){

         df_1 <- subset(x, get(i) == 1)
         df_2 <- subset(x, get(j) == 1)
         print(paste(i, j, sep = " "))
         print(t.test(df_1$DV, df_2$DV) )


     }
 }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much for your answer. This is very helpful

Comment: @SharifAmlani yw :-) happy coding :-)